# Check if value exists with array_search()

Tags: php

I have an array called `$resultstatsmatch` with the folowing output:

```
  Array
    (
        [40] => Array
            (
                [stat1] => 20
                [bonusidbonusstat0] => 40
            )
    )
```

Now I want to check if the array key `[bonusidbonusstat0]` contains the value "40". If yes, it should appear a text.

Therefore I´m using the `array_search() method` but for some reason it doesn´t work, the text is shown, no matter the value exists or not.

This is the code:

```
$bonusStat2 = "40";
$columnname2 = "bonusidbonusstat0";
$res = array_search($bonusStat2, array_column($resultstatsmatch, $columnname2));

if($res == ''){
    echo 'exists';
} else {
    echo 'notExists';
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked what `array_column` returns?

Comment: If you use foreach will work. `foreach($resultstatsmatch as $array)`

Comment: Is that ALL of the `$resultstatsmatch` array or just a bit of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `array_search`, I would recommend to use [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if `bonusStat2` exist in the result of `array_column`

```php
<?php

$array = [];
$array[40] = [];
$array[40]['stat1'] = 20;
$array[40]['bonusidbonusstat0'] = 40;

$res = array_column($array, 'bonusidbonusstat0');
$res = in_array('40', $res);

if ($res) {
    echo 'exists';
} else {
    echo 'notExists';
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYvNCgIhFEb3PsVdDGgwCwt3Fq16ChkGm4wRJhV1oIie3dR@YKi7ufd@53xudClt9250CDXSe3mDHYiOvx/BaPcTCByijGtcyIYuydGaOehTXcWi1WLZQo1XId9V7gc7zRdDXtUW/vRW/NPQpq8awYziFkqaIdJnIPWGO4I8ahgtYHXVIQbM0QPUFNSCGRsPX5zSEw)